# ElasticSearch - uninstall version 6.4.3, install version 6.4.2 - Linux Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a 3-node cluster with ElasticSearch 6.4.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.  There is nothing existing outside of the fresh install of ES - no indexes, no Kibana, no Beats, no Logstash, etc.

I have been asked to downgrade to version 6.4.2.  I have limited Linux experience, but enough to be able to run command line commands and understand the output.  Google has lead me to bits and pieces around accomplishing this, but I'd feel a lot less anxiety around it if someone with ES experience may be able to point me to something that's a bit more step-by-step.

I do have this link to download 6.4.2, but one of the things I need to know is which file to download: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-6-4-2

Comment: hope you are using the tar version to install it ? I gave step by step commands, let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure here you go with step by step guide, As I did this for you, using your version.

1. Using this link https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-6-4-2, which you mentioned, download the tar file to your local system.
2. Use `SCP` to transfer the `.tar` file to your ubuntu instance, I used my AWS ubuntu instance.

> scp -i ~/your-identity-file   ~/Desktop/elasticsearch-6.4.2.tar.gz
>   ubuntu@aws-ec2-instance-ip:/home/ubuntu

3. Untar file using `tar -xvf elasticsearch-6.4.2.tar.gz` command.
4. Go to config folder like `cd elasticsearch-6.4.2/config/` and set the proper values in `elasticsearch.config`.
5. Start the elasticsearch from bin folder `./elastic` command.

**Update:- Based on the chat with OP, Adding official ES link** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html for detailed instruction.

Comment: Hi, looks like I got the right person for this based on your name! :)  Trying this now, thanks so much for the step by step.  Yes I will use the tar version.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, Not to brag but I have given more than 150 answers in Elasticsearch tag and have been using it for years, Also if you installed 6.4.3 using tar, then no need to unistall it, just delete the folder using `rm -rf <your-es-6.4.3-foler-name> :)`

Comment: Thanks again - I was just pulled to another task, I will return to this this afternoon and advise if I have further questions.

Comment: @Stpete111, sure, feel free to comment, btw I am here for another 20 mins and these commands should not take 5-10 mins

Comment: Hi Opster, not sure if you're still online - do I need to perform these steps on all 3 nodes separately, or just the master node?

Comment: @Stpete111, you need to do the same on all your nodes, as its best to have all the ES nodes have the same versions and hope they all are on a different hosts?

Comment: HI again - sure understood.  What do you mean by "different hosts?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210331/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-stpete111).

Comment: This doesn't appear to install the chosen version as a service...